# Auto login with custom membership provider

Tags: forms-authentication

My goal is to setup a SSO-like environment (not fully support SSO), with below behaviour:

1. User logon in System_A (java)
2. When user click on a specify link, System_A will generate a security token, timestamp, and redirect the user to System_B (SharePoint with FBA) http://system_b/_forms/default.aspx?u=UserName&tkn=[SECURITY_TOKEN + TIMESTAMP with some encryption....]
3. System_B implemented custom membership provider, it makes some webservice call to System_A to validate the user session in the ValidateUser(string username, string password) method. Refer: http://blog.sharedove.com/adisjugo/index.php/2011/01/05/writing-a-custom-membership-provider-and-using-it-for-fba-forms-based-authentication-in-sharepoint-2010-from-the-scratch/

Remarks

- User can ONLY visit System_B by the link generate after logon on System_A, so it's not a real SSO situation.
- When user logout from System_B, doesn't need to logout System_A vice versa.

Everything is OK, except user unable to logout on SharePoint. here are the findings:
1. If I use normal form login flow (i.e. /_forms/default.aspx, and enter username, password)  , it has no problem in logging-out.

1. In normal form flow, it will write a cookie name FedAUTH=xxxxxxxxxxx
2. If I use auto-login link, (i.e. /_forms/default.aspx?u=UserName&tkn=[SECURITY_TOKEN + TIMESTAMP with some encryption....]), it will write a cookie name with .ASPXAUTH=xxxxxxxxxx

I customized the /_forms/default.aspx as below:

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e) {
    base.OnLoad(e);
    SetLoginInfo();

}

private void SetLoginInfo() {
    if (!IsPostBack) {

        string u = Request.Params["u"];
        string tkn = Request.Params["tkn"];
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(u) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(tkn)) {

            MembershipProvider mp = Membership.Providers["My Membership Provider"];
            if (mp.ValidateUser(u, tkn)) {
                string spname = GetSPEncodeClaimName(u);
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(spname, false);
                Page.Response.Redirect("/", false);
            }

        }
    }
}

protected string GetSPEncodeClaimName(string username) {
    string encodeName = null;
    SPClaimProviderManager mgr = SPClaimProviderManager.Local;
    if (mgr != null) {
        SPClaim claim = new SPClaim(SPClaimTypes.UserLogonName, username, "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string", SPOriginalIssuers.Format(SPOriginalIssuerType.Forms, "My Membership Provider"));
        encodeName = mgr.EncodeClaim(claim);
        encodeName = encodeName.Substring(encodeName.IndexOf(':') + 1);
    }
    return encodeName;
}
```

The problem seem come from the cookie's name, am I correct? if so, how to change the cookie name?
Is there any other better way to implement this logic?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Did you have a look at OAuth? Maybe you could implement it for your case...

Answer (score 2):

I would tell you to look into SAML based authentication and configuring SharePoint to trust your Java application as a trusted provider, but that may not be as easy as it sounds, so here is a quick fix.

1. Implement an application page (under layouts folder) and inherit from `UnsecuredLayoutsPageBase`
2. Setup your Java app to send users to this page with the token in the querystring
3. Write the following code to autenticate the user:

   ```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
       try {
           if(Request.QueryString["Token"] != null) {
               RedirectToken token = RedirectToken.Fetch(Guid.Parse(Request.QueryString["Token"]));

               if(token != null && DateTime.Now.Subtract(token.Issued).TotalMinutes < 10.0) {
                   Logger.Write("Performing auto login for user: {0} [{1}]", token.Username, token.Target);
                   Logger.Write("Current web url: {0}", SPContext.Current.Web.Url);

                   SecurityToken st = SPSecurityContext.SecurityTokenForFormsAuthentication(new Uri(SPContext.Current.Web.Url),
                       "<name>", "<name>", token.Username, "DECRYPTED_TOKEN", SPFormsAuthenticationOption.PersistentSignInRequest);

                   SPFederationAuthenticationModule.Current.SetPrincipalAndWriteSessionToken(st);
                   Response.Redirect(token.Target);
               }
               else {
                   Response.Write("Invalid token.");
               }
           }
           else {
               Response.Write("Missing token.");
           }           
       }
       catch(ThreadAbortException) {
           // do nothing...
       }
       catch(Exception x) {
           Logger.Write("Error performing auto login.", x);
           Response.Write("Error performing auto login.");
       }
   }
   ```
4. Your custom membership provider should be able to take the username and decrypted token and validate your user.

To handle the logout, you need to implement a logout page, and register it through PowerShell.
I don't have any code for it, but this should give you an idea:

- http://satishumapathy.com/2013/01/16/set-custom-signout-page-in-sharepoint-2010/